# Is it possible to use glob pattern for matching zip contents?

Tags: php, zip, php-stream-wrappers

I thought I conveniently could list any contents in a zip file using a glob pattern. But that didn't seem to work. Is there a way?

```
<?php

  $contents = glob('zip://path/to/archive.zip#subdir/*.ext');
  var_dump($contents);
```

The zip:// stream wrapper doesn't seem to return directory contents at all.

```
scandir('zip://path/to/archive.zip#subdir/');  // array(0){}
```

The documentation is not too helpful:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php

Comment: No, `glob()` will not drill into zip files.

Comment: The argument to `glob()` is a pathname, not a URL. `zip:` has no meaning in the filesystem.

Comment: You could probably unzip to php://memory or php://temp and glob there.

Comment: `nelexa/zip` has some handy functions that you might use: `$files = (new \PhpZip\ZipFile())->openFile('foo.zip')->getListFiles();`

Comment: @Barmar I thought that was a limitation of the stream wrapper and not glob.

Comment: @AbraCadaver php://memory doesn't seem to function as a directory. Otherwise that would have been great. file_put_contents('php://memory/testfile.ext', 'foo');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems here. glob() does not support stream wrappers. And the stream wrapper for zip:// does not have an implementation for listing directory contents.

So both the stream wrapper and glob() implementation would need a replacement.

What might be more convenient is to write a function that extracts data from a **ZIPArchive()** object and filter it using **fnmatch()**:

```
  function globzip($archive, $pattern, $flags = 0) {

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($archive, ZipArchive::RDONLY);

    $results = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
      $file = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
      if (fnmatch($pattern, $file, $flags)) {
        $results[] = $file;
      }
    }

    return $results;
  }
```

Can be used like this:

```
$files = globzip('/path/to/.zip', 'subdirectory/*.ext'));
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive